# Installer fails registry access permission

Tags: permissions, windows-registry, windows-10

I'm running an app install that gives a lot of "Error opening registry key with all access" messages. I run the install under my admin account and I have full permissions in regedit. As a work-around, I went into regedit and assigned Full Control to all users and all application packages but it still fails. One example that fails is an ANT task that looks like this:

```
    <win32.registry root="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment">
        <set entry="PG_HOME" value="xxx"/>
    </win32.registry>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is on Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this. I tried a bunch of things, but I think the one that made the difference was running the install from a command prompt after selecting "Run as Administrator" on that.